# How to detect adb monkey crashed the app?

Tags: android, jenkins, adb, monkey

I'm setting up a Jenkins job in order to run adb monkey on my app. I run the following command:

```
adb  shell monkey -p nl.tmg.telegraaf -v 500
```

In some cases it succeeds and sometimes it fails. However, the exit code is always 0. Hence jenkins treats it as a successful job. Anybody know how this can be prevented?

Comment: make a wrapper script which would parse the adb output and return relevant exit code?

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [Android Emulator Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Android+Emulator+Plugin#AndroidEmulatorPlugin-RunningtheAndroid%7B%7Bmonkey%7D%7Dtool) for Jenkins, which can run Monkey for you, parse the output, and change the build result accordingly.